# Best way to make async function return Vec without allocation

Tags: rust, async-await

I need an async function return multiple items without using a future streams (i.e. `futures::Stream`). The most obvious way of doing that is to return `Vec<T>`. But I would like to avoid heap allocations during these calls. It looks like the best way is to have something like this:

```
async fn read_items(offset: usize, count: usize, tmp: Vec<Item>) -> Result<Vec<Item>> {
    // Fill the tmp vector.
    Ok(tmp)
}
```

How optimial is the way above taking into account the constraints above?

Comment: This looks like a XY problem. Why can't you use a stream? Also, do you just want to re-use a `Vec`? What did you try and why it didn't work?

Comment: I can't use stream since it holds a mutable reference to a database connection which I want to reuse during iteration. Yes, I want to avoid memory allocation per each call.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that because of the way Futures works, your return value will always be stored on the heap at one point and moved around memory anyway. and if the number of item returned is unknown at compiled time, you will need a vec or other heap allocated container

Comment: also, to avoid as much allocations as possible, you can initialize the vec with a given capacity https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/alloc/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity, so you only have one allocations and can push your items basically for free

Comment: @Bamontan Incorrect. First, futures can (and are, many times) allocated on the stack (as opposed to in C++). Second, they will store up to one element because of their state machine structure.

Answer (score -1):

I think we can also use constant generics to avoid heap allocations (assuming that we know the count at compile-time):

```rust
async fn read_items<const N: usize>(offset: usize) -> Result<([Item; N], usize)> {
    let mut data = [Item::default(); N];
    // Fill the data.
    Ok((data, num))
}
```

The function will return a pair `(data, length)`.